# Pandas removing a list of different rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have list of dates and a dataframe. I want to remove those dates of dataframe which are in list.

```
bad_dates = ['2019-01-24', '2019-01-29'] 
df =              r2POADC     r2DCAC   r2ACPOA  ...   good1    bad  bad1
     2019-01-24  0.931928   0.953512  0.952798  ...   False  False  True
     2019-01-25 -1.681725  -2.163356  0.961674  ...   False  False  True
     2019-01-26 -0.879915  -1.398238  0.911883  ...   False  False  True
     2019-01-28 -1.637134  -0.718831  0.783878  ...   False  False  True
     2019-01-29 -1.839277  -6.368115  0.951883  ...   False  False  True
     2019-01-30 -0.188997  -0.566269  0.919461  ...   False  False  True
```

My code is :

```
df.drop([bad_dates],axis=0,inplace=True)
```

My current output is :

```
KeyError: "[('2019-01-24', '2019-01-29')] not found in axis"
```

It is interesting because both dates are present in index but it says both are not found in the axis (index).

I want following output:

```
 df =              r2POADC     r2DCAC   r2ACPOA  ...   good1    bad  bad1
     2019-01-25 -1.681725  -2.163356  0.961674  ...   False  False  True
     2019-01-26 -0.879915  -1.398238  0.911883  ...   False  False  True
     2019-01-28 -1.637134  -0.718831  0.783878  ...   False  False  True
     2019-01-30 -0.188997  -0.566269  0.919461  ...   False  False  True
```

Looks like! there is a small error in my code.

Comment: badDates is a list. what you want is to iterate over items in the list and if there is a match skip the line.

Comment: @Rebin Don't mind, I am new to python. Giving some code to how to do it will be of great help.

Comment: df.drop(bad_dates,axis=0,inplace=True)?

Comment: `pandas drop()` can handle lists. you have extra square bracket around `bad_dates` as @Wen-Ben says.

Comment: @Guimoute, i got error `KeyError: "['2019-01-24'] not found in axis"`

Comment: @Wen-Ben This code `df.drop(bad_dates,axis=0,inplace=True)` gave error as `KeyError: "['2019-01-24' '2019-01-29'] not found in axis"`

Comment: Did you use `set_index()` to set the dates as index?

Comment: `df.drop(pd.to_datetime(bad_dates), axis=0, inplace=True)` if the index is of type datetime.

Comment: @ayhan, This code `df.drop(pd.to_datetime(bad_dates), axis=0, inplace=True)` worked as I wanted. Thanks a ton. Yes! index is datetime type. You can answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with dates, pandas implicitly converts strings to dates most of the time. `drop`, however, is apparently an exception to that so it requires explicit conversion:

```
df.drop(pd.to_datetime(bad_dates), axis=0, inplace=True)
```